# I need a windows command line script that takes an output, edits it and creates an environmental variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, computer-name, wds

I have Asset tags embedded in BIOS. I use

wmic SYSTEMENCLOSURE get SMBiosAssetTag

This pulls the information I want but it is not formatted well:

SMBIOSAssetTag

11886

I need to just have those 5 numbers and nothing else. I will then use that variable to name the computer with a first logon script. I have spent hours on this, and I could have been done in 3 minutes if this was linux.

Note: I can't put linux tools on these builds :-(

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
WMIC SYSTEMENCLOSURE GET SMBiosAssetTag /FORMAT:VALUE
```

will make a better output:

```
(some empty lines)
SMBIOSAssetTag=CZC1296FLD
(some empty lines)
```

So, in batch you may just

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,* DELIMS==" %%v IN (WMIC SYSTEMENCLOSURE GET SMBiosAssetTag /FORMAT:VALUE) DO IF /I "%%v" == "SMBIOSAssetTag" SET SMBIOSAssetTag=%%w
```

Side note: hard part in WMIC output is handling empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, tested it myself:

```
for /f "eol=S" %%a in ('wmic SYSTEMENCLOSURE get SMBiosAssetTag^|sort') do (set var=%%a)
```

It works fine.

Mona

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic SYSTEMENCLOSURE get SMBiosAssetTag') do for /f %%b in ("%%a") do set "var=%%b"
echo %var%
```